# Как можно связать классы чтоб подобная конструкция работать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Library
clas Book

lib = Library(1, ’51 Some str., NY’)
lib += Book(‘Leo Tolstoi’, ‘War and Peace’)
lib += Book(‘Charles Dickens’, ‘David Copperfield’)
for book in lib:
# вывод в виде: [1] L.Tolstoi ‘War and Peace’
    print(book)
# вывод в виде: [‘War’, ‘Peace’]
    print(book.tag())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределить *магический метод* [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) для поддержки классом оператора `+=` и метод [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) для поддержки итерации:

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, id, address):
        self.id = id
        self.address = address
        self._books = []

    def __iadd__(self, book):
        self._books.append(book)
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        for book in self._books:
            yield book
```

Comment: Не понятно как мне связать классы

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "связать"?